# How to create a program that converts binary to decimal

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert binary to decimal, how do I change my code to be able to do that? Where did I mess up?

i tried looking at other examples, looking at java api and watching videos but i still can't figure out what mistake i have made.

```
package Calculator;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("(2) Convert binary to decimal");
            System.out.println("\n\n Please enter your choice: ");
            int choice = scan.nextInt();
            if(choice == 2){
                scan.nextLine();
                //prompt for user input
                System.out.println("Please enter a binary number: ");
                String binary = scan.nextLine();
                char[] binaryArray = binary.toCharArray();              
                int i=1;
                int integer=0;
            //potential problem somewhere around here? 
            while(i<8){
                if(binaryArray[i]==0) {
                    ++i;
                }else if(binaryArray[i]==1) {
                    switch(i) {
                    case 1:
                        integer+=128;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        integer+=64;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        integer+=32;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        integer+=16;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        integer+=8;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        integer+=4;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        integer+=2;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        integer+=1;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
            System.out.println("The decimal value of the binary number is: "+ integer);
            scan.close();
    }
}
```

}

The input is always 0. I've tried 11010110, 11111111,and 01010111. Always 0. I know the problem lies somewhere with my integer value not changing but I can't figure out what it specifically is.

Comment: There's a built-in for that: `Integer.parseInt("binary string", 2)`

Comment: Why not use `Integer.parseInt("11010110", 2)`?

Comment: Because presumably this is a pedagogical exercise.

Comment: `if(binaryArray[i]==1)` should be `if(binaryArray[i]=='1')` --- The array is an array of **characters**, not an array of digits. Same for `0` vs `'0'`

Comment: Are you going to write 32 if-else eventually? Do you sense something wrong with your code already?

Comment: You also look like you have an off-by-one error. Array indices start at zero (you'd never hit `case 8` either).

Comment: Google it. People have solved this homework problem a million times before you.

Comment: i wouldn't be able to find the problem with it just by googling, i knew what the problem was i just couldn't recognize it. I needed someone else's eyes.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are reading the input, and converting into an array of `char`.

Anywhere where you are making your comparisons to an `int`, you should instead be doing a comparison to a `char`, by wrapping your values in single quotations.

```
while(i<8){
                if(binaryArray[i]=='0') {
                    ++i;
                }else if(binaryArray[i]=='1') {
                    switch(i) {
                    case 1:
                        integer+=128;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        integer+=64;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        integer+=32;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        integer+=16;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        integer+=8;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        integer+=4;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        integer+=2;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        integer+=1;
                        ++i;
                        break;
                    }
            }
```

Comment: I could, but that's not an answer. I interpreted the question as "Why is my output always 0" Here is my answer.

Comment: thanks alot! i cant believe the problem was so simple

Comment: Hi Nate, If this answered your question, please mark my response as the answer to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out that you have got confused between `0` and `1`, and `'0' and`'1'`.

Other problems:

- Your `i` starts at 1, so you miss the most significant bit;
- You will never actually hit `case 8:` in the switch because of the `while (i < 8)` loop guard.
- This doesn't work unless you enter exactly 8 bits.

You can write the entire while loop in a much more concise way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < binaryArray.length; i++) {
  integer *= 2; // shift the digits along by 1 place
  if (binaryArray[i] == '1') {
    integer += 1; // set the least significant bit.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get away from all those switch statements.

Say you have "10101101" as input.
set val = 0;
Then either multiply by val by 2 or shift left 1 bit.  They're the same. It is important
you do this before adding the next bit.

Start from the left and if it's a '1', add a 1 to val. Otherwise, add 0.
Then repeat starting at multiply until you've gone thru the string.

val should then have the decimal version when you print it.